# Is the mapping between C# nullable types and the F# option type recommended?

Tags: c#, f#, interop

Given the following F# record type:

```ml
type TestRecord =
    { CustomerId: option<int>
      Email: option<string> }
```

I can create instances of this type from C# with

```cs
int? customerId = null;
string email = null;

var tr = new TestRecord(customerId, email);
```

If I process the record in F# coming this way from C#, each null C# value becomes a None on the F# side and non-null C# values become Some x on the F# side.

This automatic conversion from C# nullables to F# options is very convenient for the purpose I'm planning to use it. However, I'm unclear on whether this is one of those things that works but is not recommended. I've searched for some docs on this aspect of C# to F# interop but can find a definitive answer.

Is this automatic conversion behavior recommended?

Comment: I wonder if I've run into this: https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/774

Comment: Yes, that ‘automatic conversion’ you refer to in that issue, has since been implemented, I believe in F# 5. `Nullable` is largely compatible to `Option` (semantics are a little different, but in practice that shouldn’t matter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [F# Language Specification](https://fsharp.org/specs/language-spec/4.1/FSharpSpec-4.1-latest.pdf) 18.4.2 `Option.None` is represented as `null`, so it should be safe to rely upon.

Comment: No, `Some x` is not represented as `x`. That wouldn’t be possible. It’s valid to have [`Some null` where `null` is some ref type](https://sharplab.io/#v2:DYLgZgzgNAJiDUAfA9gBwKYDsAEBlAnhAC7oC2AsAFCnIwCuw62AKusdgLxXbaNHZgAFAEpOeZKSaDMDUNmIAnAJaYA5sKA=). Conversely, `Nullable null` is not possible (in fact, you cannot use it with a ref type).

Comment: That said, it is deliberate that F# implemented auto conversion from nullables value types to option types. They overlap in functionality (wrt value types).